# Spring integration extract payload within handler

Tags: lambda, spring-integration, dsl

> I'm new to spring integration using DSL and have difficulty in
>   extracting payload within http handler, to dynamically construct the URI.
>   The integration flow below is triggered by AccountList Gateway and it adds the
>   customer id value to the message on invocation on channel
>   "accountListFlow.input". And the payload contains just  '123766123'
>   and thats the customer id passed.
>
> Thereafter the message is enriched with header and then passed
>   downstream to handler.
>
> I require customer id to be extracted in the handler to dynamically construct the URI. I tried generic handler and cast payload to String but fails saying can't cast lambda object. Any help here how to
>   extract the payload as a whole which is the customer id when
>   constructing the URI, please ?

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface AccountList {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "accountListFlow.input")
    List<String> accountListFlow(String customerId);
}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow accountListFlow() {
    return flow -> flow.publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s.applySequence(true)
                            .subscribe(f -> f
                                       .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("X-CUST-IP-Id","145.26.54.24"))
                            .handle((o, map) -> 
Http.outboundGateway("http://get-customers-product-holdings-gb-hbeu-v3-v3-cert.cf.wgdc-drn-01.cloud.uk/api/customers/"+(String)o+"/product-holdings?categoryCode=cc,cbs,sd")
    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
    .mappedRequestHeaders("X-CUST-IP-Id")
    .expectedResponseType(String.class)
    .extractPayload(true)).channel("aggregateAccount.input"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
.handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://get-customers-product-holdings-gb-hbeu-v3-v3-cert.cf.wgdc-drn-01.cloud.uk/api/customers/{customer}/product-holdings?categoryCode=cc,cbs,sd")
    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
    .mappedRequestHeaders("X-CUST-IP-Id")
    .expectedResponseType(String.class)
    .uriVariable("customer", "payload")
    .extractPayload(true))
.channel("aggregateAccount.input"));
```

Notice the `{customer}` variable in the url.

Comment: Many thanks Gary. It works as expected. I couldn't use payload as value but uriVariable("customerId", message -> message.getPayload().toString()) resolved it!

Comment: Sorry, `payload` should have been `"payload"`.